# Copy and paste storyboard controller into xib file. Supported or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to refactor out a storyboard controller to a separate xib, for better reusablity.
The controller extends UITableViewController.

I can select the controller in the storyboard, hit Cmd-C, create an empty xib file using the New File wizard, and finally paste the controller into the xib.

It seems to work ok. The UI elements are there, the outlets are there, etc. It forgets the orientation and the size (portrait, Retina 4-inch), but I can easily set that in the properties pane to the right in xcode.

However when trying to use this xib I get a crash with error message:

> loaded the "MyController" nib but the view outlet was not set.

When I try to connect Files Owner to the table view (which is the top view in a controller extended from UITableViewController), xcode won't let me connect them.

My question: **Is it unsupported to copy-paste a controller from a storyboard to a xib?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely jamming a tableViewController into a nib and there is no outlet to hook the view to. When you do Ctl-C in the storyboard make sure you copy the UITable not the UITableViewController. If not you can try to manually create the outlet in the controller but you might have to jump through hoops to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, but if I only copy the UITableView, won't I loose all my outlets and other connections to the controller? I guess it's not such a big job to reconnect them though ;) But the question is, is copying and pasting an entire controller meant to work?

Comment: Yes it is meant to work. I have done it many times but in your case you are not pasting something that fit where you are putting it. You will lose the links and you might also have to change your controller slightly because you are going to go from a `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>`. You will also have to link the tableView to an `IBOutlet`

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on why a UITableViewController does not fit in a xib? Does it have something to do with the self.view property is not exposed the normal way?

Comment: I ended up creating one more storyboard. The copy and paste of my UITableViewController into the new storyboard worked perfectly. Nothing was lost and I achieved the goal of being able to reuse my controller.

Comment: It's because as far as I know a xib can't contain a graphical representation of the controller but a storyboard can. This is why is flawless when you copy it into another storyboard.